# how to override left:0 using CSS or Jquery?

Tags: css, css-position

I have an element, which has the following CSS:

```
.elem {
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  width: 60%;
  z-index: 1000;
  }
```

The element does not span the whole screen. I would like it to "align" to the right hand side of the screen.

This would be easy, if I just removed *left: 0*, but I cannot tamper with the above CSS, so I need some CSS or Jquery to override, disable or remove the *left:0* CSS.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 260, accepted):

The default value for `left` is `auto`, so just set it to that and you will "reset" it.

```
.elem {
  left: auto;
}
```

Make sure that the above comes after the original CSS file.

Comment: THANKS! I was trying '', but that did not get me anymore. Good to know.

Comment: @frequent You could use values like '' if you were using Javascript, yes, but not in CSS. Anyway, but didn't you say you couldn't tamper with the stylesheet? In that case, a `style="left:auto"` attribute in the element itself would do the trick, overriding the stylesheet.

Comment: THANK YOU!! it was exactly what I was looking for! I'm moving the floating Shield icon from OneTrust, make sure you add "left: auto !important;" to override the CSS that comes from OneTrust

Answer (score 11):

Using CSS:

```
.elem {
    left: auto;
}
```

Using JQuery:

```
$(".elem").css("left", "auto");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `auto` property in CSS, which is equal to the default value.

Answer (score 2):

With jquery:

```
$(".elem").css("left", "");
```

Comment: doesn't this reset it to specified value (in this case '0')?

Comment: @Antonio: This would actually be setting an invalid "left" html attribute like `<div left="0">` rather than changing css. While Jan's comment still stands (i.e. no need for JS), it could be done with `$(".elem").css("left", "");` or something.

Comment: Ops, that's true... edit and put this possible solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whether this style you extracted is an external or an internal one, you can override it with an internal one such as:

```
.elem {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    width: 60%;
    z-index: 1000;
  }
```