# Twitter's Bootstrap 3 Dropdown mega menu going out of browser

Tags: drop-down-menu, alignment, twitter-bootstrap-3, megamenu

I'm trying to make a mega menu using Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 and it works fine. But when it comes to the last list item with mega menu, the dropdown goes out of the browser, since it starts from left. How can i make the last list item's dropdown only starts from right to left. I've tried to use "pull-right", but it doesn't work properly. When using "pull-right" for the main menu list item, the dropdown starts from extreme right of the navigation bar. I want it like, the dropdown perfectly right aligned to the parent `<li>`'s relative position.

Comment: Refer this http://wsnippets.com/responsive-ajax-based-drop-menu-twitter-bootstrap-jquery-mysql-php/

Answer (score 1):

**css**

```
.navbar-nav > li:last-child > .dropdown-menu {
    left: auto;
    right: 0; }
```

references:

- [how to override left:0 using CSS or Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102915/how-to-override-left0-using-css-or-jquery)
- [Changing CSS for last <li>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329841/changing-css-for-last-li)